# Inserting text below image on download

Tags: asp.net, imagedownload

I have a collection of images that a client can download should they desire. However, the boss came to me with a requirement to try and add text at the bottom of image. Unfortunately due to space constraints on the server, I can't simply use Javascript to add the information to the bottom of the page when it is uploaded.

Ideally the format should two rows with two cells each. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  We are unsure what "space constraints" you are referring to.  Do you have a screenshot of what you are talking about?

Comment: @JasonGeiger "Space Constraints" I mean I can't just add the information to the image when it is stored on the server. I need to be able to add the text to the bottom when the image is being downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
http://mvark.blogspot.com/2004/12/code-programmatically-add-text-to.html